# Learning about fitness for skiing

Tags: strength-training, flexibility, joints, stamina, skiing

I hope this question doesn't feel like a get-rich-quick scheme for fitness.

I am struggling to get/stay fit for skiing. (Leisure).

I have not been able to find any coaches which focus on fitness for skiing (rather than general fitness or skiing technique). So I am thinking about buying a whole load of books on various aspects, but obviously, physical fitness is an incredibly large topic which spans many professions, so I am wondering if teaching myself what I need to know is feasible.

In short, I want to know what exercises a professional skier would embark on in a comprehensive regime. I have not found any books on this particular subject unfortunately. While I could get books on general aspects such as:

- Joint mobility
- Stretches
- Stamina
- Strength

It would be an awful lot of learning and reading. Especially if I want to know which of the above exercises would/wouldn't help with skiing, to avoid spending time working out on unnecessary exercises.

Can anyone recommend a learning path that cuts to the chase?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked ski websites? If you're really interested in skiing, you should be able to glean these information from ski websites.

Comment: Cross country or downhill skiing?

Comment: The book "Total skiing" might help you out; it has an approach that targets the kind of exercises that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [good summary](http://exercise.about.com/od/healthinjuries/a/skiing.htm) of muscles involved in skiing (in my experience, it is based on importance):

- Quadriceps.
- Hamstrings and Glutes.
- Inner and Outer Thighs.
- Calves.
- Abs and Back.
- Arms.

If you would like to get/stay fit for skiing you should target these muscles.

Based on personal experience, the following exercises prepare me the best for the skiing season and build the aforementioned muscles:

1. Cycling, roller-blading - fun, similar to skiing experience. Also perfect exercises for improving joint mobility and stamina. If you do some uphill cycling, you could also work on your muscle strength.
2. Squats, deadlifts - I'm personally following Starting Strength program. Very good exercises for developing your legs and your body overall.
3. Abs - any abs exercise will do.
4. Pull-ups, bench presses - for developing your arms.
5. Jogging - just to stay fit and develop your stamina.

From get-rich-quick perspective, I picked up skiing very quickly thanks to two exercises: roller-blading and squats.

Few more useful links: [Building up your skiing muscles](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/hi/sa/special_events/winter_sport/newsid_3249000/3249116.stm) and [The Best Stretches And Exercices For Skiing And Snowboarding](http://iglimpse.co.uk/wp_how_to_prevent_back_pain/2012/12/23/the-best-stretches-and-exercices-for-skiing-and-snowboarding/).

Comment: Good lists - I would add stair-climbing - actual stairs and not just a stair-climbing machine.

Comment: Your answer recommended Starting Strength, which is what I was going to reply with. 99.99% of people looking for sport specific fitness should start with comprehensive well rounded strength training.

Answer (score 0):

I ski in Austria and Italy with quite a bit of off piste / black run fun. I generally keep pretty fit, but in the 6 to 8 weeks before I go skiing I shift a couple of my workouts to favour squats, dead lifts and box jumps (with ankle weights when possible).